# Subtracting ASCII character/values in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, text, ascii, symbols

This a function of a code I wrote that subtracts two values which are both of type character over and over again to get a text, but the result is not a text of string but symbols instead.

I checked by **cout** that the **keyLetters** and **analysis** have both correct values in ASCII and clear letters before converting them to **int**.

The **lengthText** is correct too.

**keyLetters** is a word of 5 letters.

```
void originalText(string analysis, string keyLetters) {
    int lengthText=analysis.length();
    char originText[2000];
    int hold;
    int k;
    for (int i=0; i<lengthText; i++) {
        if(i%5==0)
            k=0;
        hold=keyLetters[k]-analysis[i];
        if (hold<=0) 
            hold*=-1;
        originText[i]=(char)hold;
        cout<<originText[i];
        k++;
    }

}
```

A screenshot of the result I get:

[image: The result I get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that since the encrypted text has been generated by %26 (mod 26), the values of the letters that was larger than 26 lost its original values. So when they have been decrypted, they were generated as incorrect letters. That's why I had to return the 26 they have lost, before doing the subtraction procedure, as it will be subtracted correctly.

```
void originalText(string analysis, string keyLetters) {
    int lengthText=analysis.length();
    char originText[2000];
    int hold;
    int k;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthText; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            k=0;
        }
        hold = (analysis[i]+26)-keyLetters[k];
        if (hold < 0) {
            hold *= -1;
        }
        hold%=26;
        originText[i] = (char)hold + 'a';
        cout << originText[i];
        k++;
    }
}
```

**The result of it:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Both `keyLetters` and `analysis` consist of characters between 'a' and 'z'.
That means the difference between characters in these two can be from -25 ('a' - 'z') up to +25 ('z' - 'a').
Then you want to represent this difference using ascii characters, multiplicing by -1 the negative case. Nothing simpler:

```
void originalText(string analysis, string keyLetters) {
    int lengthText = analysis.length();
    char originText[2000];
    int hold;
    int k;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthText; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            k = 0;
        }
        hold = keyLetters[k] - analysis[i];
        if (hold < 0) {
            hold *= -1;
        }
        originText[i] = (char)hold + 'a';
        cout << originText[i];
        k++;
    }
}
```

You need shift the value in range <0,25> to printable small ascii characters <'a','z'> by adding a 'a' ascii value, that is 97. The range <0,25> in [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) are just control characters.

This will result in:

> The decrypted text:
>   oncegpmnahioethejewasalihtpegirpehmwantedhoplacallthedacandihedidnmtcareabmuhhejshudcahallinschomlherlarenhsgetangjcatherallhhetimebutihedidnmtcareabmuhhejparentifeelingiwhethejthecareangrymriadiheeaisgchabadgirplehuinohbeashejnefejeverhakecaremfevejchhingarogndcogsharhingfjoocogrlarenhstilpcogshudieiatichooltakealpthatieriogslcbestmfpucknmtheshorcdmesnohfiniihherethereismojetmihthatgirlonedaceenhtmschomlwhichiiuniveriitcactualpcbgtleolletendhosacabogtitschmolhhatihiimojecommonandidonnohknmwanyeacthatgirlofcogriewenhtognivejsitymrcollegeifihavetmsacwhenihegohopdejlikeehenshebecameeighheenceariopdsmahuniversitcthereeaiapotmfitudcforhejtodoehichihehohallcicrewgpsmshecjiedandcriedalohahnighhsfhejshecamhmmeandherkindpajentsasqedhejabmuhthereasmnforhejunitmppabpeteajsthaheairgnningouhfjomhejeyesconhinuogspchmwevejsherefgsedtmtellmrsacanyhhingiinceiheeantedtmshayalmnehhatnighthereishwasfglfilledsoathhahnighhshesleltaloneinthedarqeihhmutanconebesideihejtmeahchhejandtmtakecajeofherinhersleepingasshedidhoherlajenhsanditgdiesehenshewascoungersmthecccpehasgothejrogndshapnotfrmmnmwherebgtbecauseofareaionandthatjeaionisbecauiehhingieillcomebackholeolleafhejthecdidhheminanctimeeihhmutanceajningmralejt

As to why this doesn't give the correct text, I leave that to OP, because i don't get this method of encryption.

The whole program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
string encryptText(string, string);
string cryptanalyzeText(string);
void originalText(string, string);
int main() {
    string text, analysis;
    string key;
    text = "onceuponatimetherewasalittlegirlwhowantedtoplayallthedayandshedidnotcareaboutherstudyatallinschoolherparentsgetangryatherallthetimebutshedidnotcareaboutherparentsfeelingswhethertheyareangryorsadshewassuchabadgirlletusnotbeasherneverevertakecareofeverythingaroundyoustartingfromyourparentstillyoustudiesatschooltakeallthatseriouslybestoflucknothestorydoesnotfinishherethereismoretoitthatgirlonedaywenttoschoolwhichisuniversityactuallybutpeopletendtosayaboutitschoolthatitismorecommonandidonnotknowanywaythatgirlofcoursewenttouniversityorcollegeifihavetosaywhenshegotolderlikewhenshebecameeighteenyearsoldsoatuniversitytherewasalotofstudyforhertodowhichshetotallyscrewupsoshecriedandcriedalotatnightsftershecamhomeandherkindparentsaskedheraboutthereasonforherunstoppabletearsthatwasrunningoutfromhereyescontinuouslyhoweversherefusedtotellorsayanythingsinceshewantedtostayalonethatnightherwishwasfulfilledsoatthatnightshesleptaloneinthedarkwithoutanyonebesideshertowatchherandtotakecareofherinhersleepingasshedidtoherparentsandstudieswhenshewasyoungersothecyclehasgotherroundshapnotfromnowherebutbecauseofareasonandthatreasonisbecausethingswillcomebacktopeopleaftertheydidtheminanytimewithoutanywarningoralert";
    analysis = "qegegrfrafkdittgiiwmurpifvcigutcahayrrtqfkspxcpelxvyidmarrdejvhippfxcmtvebawkledukydkckelxkewctqfphqtgerqpkwgqvrrgdarxhqtrplfjvxiygsytejvhippfxcmtvebawkledrrvezvjjeqnzrgeyyittgixhqarvempxvyatjedejvaaeulghmdrhgutcpefwjrofdvestgirehgiivqtkekqerveahvzedaklizirvogpucogukerfkekfdqdcogtgerqpkwtunccogukydugjeteeysoxvroemncxhmvjiruqlwlkdvwtahcycwpfxhquksrkffiszqkjizkjlhqtvxhqtvmsyqiitakkxhmvxmrxqeidmaninfvfwctqfpwtktliewemvqtjmtkctxumnccbgvgiobnvxezfkssmarfogvzxsojfslfjrxifkjqodgtsmyqeenpkusnzqkonayrryicpxhmvxmrxqwgogtjiwqpkxogpzzeduzxyattslxgxiirkyevqvfwakyyinejvkofqchednzoeijvrstgsicmoviisjkiezavereqchsackynuxvvsuvpxhqtvaaeccstahjxupawsrtgixopqnliojjlefqkelxajgrqyltsauyicdkvhazftviqfrpofckrisjkwffgiwhqerqhaovenpjvvkuputadgexsmubidtgiebawkxhqtvesapwsrtgiynevftpmdcitqciwttckaaetlrnupxsufhismtgiiyqutsnfkeyogucchayvzeduyirqhlwepvfxexnfvsmarryfjzrgekegeejvaazvvhtaukeymnfrefjrxnuiyxhqtnmstyrwfgnwmlxguwomvklafpzkhfuyisxggxaxqeiizvyidmtbaifjfytmppsnqdvwipgjledvfaafeyledcehtavroeociiorjvvizjvvsxgvtizirwstgumdfqyirbciinfurrdevlhiqunlezuyiwmupsuzivvsavyickecihmuxsttgivogpuwhmrestrtfqnayyirqdlxbqerysqqwerqcjsnmpuxhmviiaeqemsngteuegklizijaixntsmqdrgkfqgiobnveffgixhqaumdfjvqizcectuovaifjfytmppaadpzrgatrpedv";

    cout<<"\n1- The original text:\n"<<text;
    cout<<"\n\nEnter a key of type string: ";
    key = "cream";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"The text after it has been encrypted:\n"<<encryptText(text, key)<<endl;

    cout<<"\n2- An encrpted text:\n"<<analysis;
    string keyLetters= cryptanalyzeText(analysis);
    cout<<"\n\nThe key is: "<<keyLetters<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"The decrypted text:\n";
    originalText(analysis, keyLetters);
    cout<<endl<<endl;;

    return 0;
}
string encryptText(string text, string key) {
    int lengthText=text.length();
    int lengthKey=key.length();
    int count=0;

    for (int i=0; i<lengthText; i++) {
        text[i]=key[count];
        if (count<lengthKey-1)
            count++;
        else
            count=0;
    }
    return text;
}
string cryptanalyzeText(string analysis) {
    string keyLetters="aaaaa";
    char ch;
    int i;
    int lengthText=analysis.length();
    for (int keyPlace=0; keyPlace<6 ; keyPlace++) {
        int alphabet[26]={0};
        for (i=keyPlace; i<lengthText; i=i+5) {
            ch=analysis[i];
            alphabet[ch - 'a']++;
        }

        int max=alphabet[0];
        int maxPlace=0;
        for (int j=1; j<26; j++) {
            if(max<alphabet[j]) {
                max=alphabet[j];
                maxPlace=j;
            }
        }
        keyLetters[keyPlace]=maxPlace-4;
        if (keyLetters[keyPlace]<0) 
            keyLetters[keyPlace]+=26+97;
        else
            keyLetters[keyPlace]+=97;
    }
    return keyLetters;
}
void originalText(string analysis, string keyLetters) {
    int lengthText=analysis.length();
    char originText[2000];
    int hold;
    int k;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthText; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            k=0;
        }
        hold = keyLetters[k] - analysis[i];
        if (hold < 0) {
            hold *= -1;
        }
        originText[i] = (char)hold + 'a';
        cout << originText[i];
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solving the switch problem and for the last function issue. As you have explained the point I was stuck at, then I can say that my problem is solved.

Comment: It has been solved.

Comment: @TasneemZh if this is a good solution to your problem you should accept this answer. It marks the question as answered and makes the answer stand out better. Kamil gets a few bonus points as well.

Comment: @user4581301, I would do that if the answer was complete and/or if I didn't figure what was wrong in the code. But his/her answer was of a great help to me.